# AngulajrJS filter output html

Tags: angularjs

Hi I am writing a filter which takes and array and returns a comma delimited string.
When i append some HTML it is not showing in the output.

Below is my code

```
 $scope.authors = [{ "authorName": 'Robin', "price": 40, "link": 'http://www.google.com' },
                    { "authorName": 'Chetan', "price": 400, "link": 'http://www.bing.com' },
                     { "authorName": 'Jack Wilson', "price": 450, "link": 'http://www.facebook.com'}
]
```

My Filter

```
    myApp.filter('formatAuthorName', function () {

    return function (input) {
        var str = [];
        var totalString = '';
        if (input.length > 1) {

            for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
                var name = input[i];
                **str.push('<a href='**name.link**'>'+name.authorName+'</a>');**
            }
            totalString = str.join(', ');
            return totalString;

        }
        return totalString;

    };
});
```

Also how to bind href to link from Scope ??.

Thanks

Comment: A custom directive is better suited for outputting HTML than a filter.

Comment: I will later refactor to a directive, but as of now is there any way to solve using filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For outputting HTML that interacts with scope, a directive is more suitable than a filter.

This answer expands on the solution originally proposed by ajk.

[Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/htiFWYG5S31UurJrFrAm?p=preview)

**Directive**

```
   app.directive('formatAuthorNames', function() { 
      return {
         restrict: 'A',
         scope: { authors: '=' },
         template: 
          '<span ng-repeat="author in authors">
             <a ng-href="{{ author.link }}">{{ author.authorName }}</a>
             <span ng-if="$index < authors.length-1">, </span>
          </span>',
          link: function(scope, elem, attr) { 
              // access scope here
          }
      }
   });
```

**HTML**

```
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller='MyController'> 
       <div authors="authors" format-author-names></div>
  </body>
```

Comment: I think a directive is a bit of overkill, but still a solid example for op so +1. You have it so tightly coupled to the model (authors) that it could make it hard to reuse for say, `publishers`. IMOE I find it helpful to decouple the directives from the model to keep it multipurpose and utilitarian. I.e. instead of 'authors', 'nameLinks`...`ng-repeat=name in nameLinks`... then I can use it for authors, companies, cars, whatever.

Comment: I think the nature of scopes and binding kind of makes you conform an directive to an object model.  If you are suggesting generalizing the object model to something more general, I agree.

Comment: +1 This is a logical expansion of my suggestion - nice job, and thanks for the nod.

Answer (score 2):

Use $sce in your filter if you want to render html:

```
<div ng-bind-html="authors | formatAuthorName"></div>
```

JS:

```
app.filter('formatAuthorName', ['$sce',
    function($sce) {

      return function(input) {
          var str = [];
          var totalString = '';
          if (input.length > 1) {

              for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
                  var name = input[i];
                  str.push('<a href=' + name.link + '>' + name.authorName + '</a>');
              }
              totalString = str.join(', ');

          }

          return $sce.trustAsHtml(totalString);

     };  
   }
]);
```

**[DEMO PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/nfsuAzf1C55tqsLJu08T?p=preview)**

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that a filter is what you're actually looking for here. You will probably be better served by using [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) in combination with [ng-href](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref). Something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="author in authors">
  <a ng-href="{{ author.link }}">{{ author.authorName }}</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Should always still put an href="" link with it.

Comment: @cerd I'm not sure why that would be necessary. Most of the examples I've seen for ng-href do not include a plain href attribute at all. In speaking with more experienced Angular folks, I haven't found a good reason for adding href="". Can you point to any justification for that? I'm honestly curious!

Comment: not officially. We were having SEO issues without it however.

Answer (score 0):

try using `ng-href` instead of a filter

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref

Hope this helps.